# how to find most searched articles which are NOT yet in wikipedia using php and wikipedia api?

Tags: php, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm looking for algorithm in php which permit to get most searched terms (articles) which are not yet  in wikipedia (red links) (or one of the subprojects) using wikipedia API or wikipedia [pagecounts dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/). I know already about statsgrok statistics (maintainer of this project Henrik do not respond on his page on wikipedia) , but it do not provide any information about "red links". I would like to obtain statistics about situation where user put some word in search page in wikipedia and wikipedia propose to create this page, because this word are not yet in wikipedia.

**EDIT**: Actually, wikimedia bugzilla already has this bug reported: [Bug 6373 — Provide a list of unsuccessful searches](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6373) registered in 2006, but last activity on this bug was registered in 2012-04-02 18:58 UTC... So, it's gonna be a long way to fixing this problem, i think Perhaps, somebody found something palliative to resolve this problem?

Comment: How would you differentiate between terms that should be articles and search terms that don't make sense as article titles?

Comment: @svick on the first step, i would like to get only raw data about search terms, because the _main goal_ it's to obtain raw data of most searched terms. Secondly, i think i will use some of open sourced dictionary or some open dictionary api.

Comment: @svick Actually, it's pretty simple: i will range all searched terms by frequency and at the top of  the list i will obtain the most appropriate terms for future articles and at the end of the list the meaningless words.

Answer (score 1):

You should [file a bug](http://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/) to request that this information be exposed somewhere on [wikistats](http://stats.wikimedia.org/).

Alternatively, start a discussion on [wikitech-l](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/wikitech-l) as I'm sure other people are interested in getting this sort of data.

Comment: I think, i'm gonna file a bug, but it's very surprising that during 11 years of using and developing mediawiki this function has not been implemented or asked by no one...

Comment: For reference, currently implemented lists can be found at [Special:WantedPages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WantedPages) (outdated, and not filterable for main namespace) and [WikiProject Missing encyclopedic articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:MISSING) (manually maintained). Also, as a curiosity, the very oldest comment in the [talk page for Special:WantedPages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Special:WantedPages) is "Statistics for failed searches" – so people have wanted this for a long time indeed.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping track of "searched but not found" searches in a DB table and the number of times they're searched in a separate field?

This can be done very easily. But then you have to handle the difference in titles people will search for, or simply split them into words and keep track of the **words** only (ignoring grammatical propositions etc)

Comment: I would like to access actual [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) with wikipedia API or pagecounts dumps, i don't have access to their database, it's not my own project on wikimedia engine... So, it's not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **[list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aWest.andrew.g/Popular_redlinks)** maintained by User:West.andrew.g, which for the time being may be the best resource to get that information. The page is updated every week. You can extract data from that page, or implement the same approach as he did if you want different parameters (a higher update frequency, red links with less than 1k views/week, etc.). He seems to be getting the data from the [Wikimedia dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/) and querying the servers for each entry above the 1k views/week threshold.

By the way, it turns out stats.grok.se *does* collect stats on red links ([example](http://stats.grok.se/en/latest/ISO_3166,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)), although it presents no compiled list of such pages.